# InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute MatMul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor [Op:MatMul]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Here is my code:

```
training_loss=[]
val_loss=[]

for epoch in range(1000):
  loss,v_loss = train(X_train1, y_train1,X_val1,y_val1)
  training_loss.append(loss)
  val_loss.append(v_loss)
  
  print('Epoch %d: Training Loss = %.4f, validation_loss= %.4f' % (epoch, float(loss),float(v_loss)))


print('Final Weights after 100 epochs:')
print('###############################################################################')
print(weights)

print('Final Bias after 100 epochs:')
print('###############################################################################')
print(bias)
```

I tried casting X and y into float32, like below.
Y = Y.astype('float32')
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')

But I still get the error.

I was expecting this to print to the final weights and bias.

Comment: I want to add that prior to splitting data, my dataset under use has all integer datatypes. Int64. I tried converting the dataset (after split) into float32 by using the "astype". Whether I do that or  not, I get the above error.

Comment: Hi @Curious! It is expecting a double tensor.Try again after changing datatype to np.double or float64.